# iOS Storyboard equivalent of - (id)initWithNibName and ViewControllers

Tags: xcode, storyboard, viewcontroller

I have 2 questions. Since Apple has moved to Storyboards from XIB files, I'd like to ask what is the equivalent of `- (id)initWithNibName`

I currently have this code in my viewcontroller.m file

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

What would be the equivalent init method for this when using storyboards?

Also, another beginner question: If I dragged a View Controller to the storyboard, how do I link the view controller to my view controller class? I'm not familiar because the template always do these things for me.

Answer (score 1):

View Controllers are initialized through `-initWithCoder:`, but you should do any [customization in -awakeFromNib](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW11).

As for setting the view controller type in the storyboard, it's in the inspector for that scene. I strongly encourage you to read the whole guide I linked to above, as it will cover these topics and the next 3 or 4 questions you'll have related to how storyboards are different.